# Is there a possibility of storing a .txt file in a .exe file or atleast hiding it from user view?

Tags: c, file, executable, text-files, file-conversion

Is there a possibility to include a text file in a .exe file?  or atleast hide it from the user view? I mean let us take an example,I have a target.exe file in which it opens and reads the contents of a data.txt file and yes its working perfect with my computer But when i transfer these target.exe file without a data.txt file to some other computer where you dont have the required data.txt file.It results an error and the thing I want you to know is data.txt file has some information like example a contact info which is a confidential text.When someone runs these .exe file he should enter the name and the data is displayed about the contact info but it works only if you have data.txt file. But i want the data.txt file to be hidden it cannot be accessed normally.The data in data.txt file can be accessed only through .exe file.How could I solve it? and remember i should give my friends only the .exe file and using that .exe file they can save thier data and display contact info. Does any one have any idea to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can include any user data into recource and link it with your .exe

[Resources in Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_%28Windows%29)

[Resource compiler reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381042%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

[LoadResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Let me go throught it andrey if i get the thing i want i would accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

If the exe opens the file, then it is nearly impossible to prevent users from accessing the contents of that file. If you store it as a raw resource, then one can use a resource editor to view it. If you do some sort of basic encryption, then using ProcExplorer, one could view string in the process to see the information when the program executes. You could use DRM style protections, but that seems like overkill.

The answer to your general question is yes, you can store resources in an EXE file and then the EXE can open and load those resources at runtime.

Comment: create resource file, reference your .txt file via RT_RCDATA, compile resource using resource compiler and link with your exe, load it from app using LoadResource in runtime